# Issues with checkboxes updating join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, join

Theres a lot of stuff around that is similar but nothing actually addresses this particular circumstance. I would like to preface by saying im still new in the Rails world.

So i have a User table and a Skill table and corresponding models.

I have created a join table to connect the 2 and have a HABTM relationship between the 2.

SKILL MODEL

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

USER MODEL

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end
```

JOIN TABLE MIGRATION
class CreateJoinTableSkillsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
  def change
    create_join_table :skills, :users do |t|
       t.index [:skill_id, :user_id]
       t.index [:user_id, :skill_id]
    end
  end
end
```

ADDSKILL METHOD (In skills controller)

```
def addSkill
     @user.id = current_user.id
     @skill.id = Skill.find(params[:id])
     params[:user_id, :skill_id]
     redirect_to user_path
end
```

RELEVANT ROUTE?

```
put 'skills/addSkill' => 'skills#addSkill'
```

index.html.erb (skills)

```
  <% commerceCategory.each do |skill| %>
    <ul>
      <%= button_to skill.title, :method => "addSkill" %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Submit Button
`<%= submit_tag "Update Skills"%>`

So basically i want:

a) `skill.title` to be a checkbox of itself (the name within the checkbox not one alongside it)

b)once its clicked, it will assign that particular skill to the current_user.id via the join table and redirect to the users show page to show the skills that user has.

I have tried so many different things and i cant seem to make it work.

Ive read all over that the has many through is a preferential association especially since i will be wanting to add varying degrees of skill for each skill eventually.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rails 4 + PGres

Comment: Your view and controller are inconsistent and messed up.  Do you want the user to select multiple skills at one time, and then submit the form?  Then you should be using check boxes inside the loop, not buttons.  Similarly, your controller action needs to handle multiple skill_ids.  Read the Rails Guide section on form helpers  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html